# Paypal Chained Payment IPN Won't Stop Callbacks

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment, chained

I'm having serious issues trying to get Paypal to stop IPN callbacks. After I verify the transaction and process it on my end with my IPN listener, I send the message directly via HTTP Post back to Paypal. I log the return message which always comes back as VERIFIED.

This is the content of my post back to Paypal, each val is separated by a | for readability

`Form Vals: transaction[0].is_primary_receiver:true | transaction[0].id_for_sender_txn:4YY80224KU744182S | log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction:false | transaction[0].receiver:za@gmail.com | action_type:PAY | ipn_notification_url:http://www.example.com/Paypal/IPNListener | transaction[1].paymentType:SERVICE | transaction[0].amount:USD 1.55 | charset:windows-1252 | transaction_type:Adaptive Payment PAY | transaction[1].id_for_sender_txn:0FS22745TN9966034 | transaction[1].is_primary_receiver:false | transaction[0].status:Completed | notify_version:UNVERSIONED | transaction[0].id:5B218293JN593094R | cancel_url:http://www.example.com/Paypal/PaymentCanceledConfirmation | transaction[1].status_for_sender_txn:Completed | transaction[1].receiver:admin@example.com | verify_sign:AiPC9BjkCyDFQXbSkoZcgqH3hpacAEFoy0ipZhsKn7zJVWqtp2H1UZjq | sender_email:example@hotmail.com | fees_payer:EACHRECEIVER | transaction[0].status_for_sender_txn:Completed | return_url:http://www.example.com/Paypal/PaymentConfirmation | transaction[0].paymentType:SERVICE | transaction[1].amount:USD 0.07 | reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error:false | tracking_id:10 | transaction[1].pending_reason:NONE | pay_key:AP-7DV229946G566022G | transaction[1].id:490095471X083615J | transaction[0].pending_reason:NONE | status:COMPLETED | transaction[1].status:Completed | payment_request_date:Thu Feb 26 15:01:35 PST 2015 |`

This is the code that I use to post the REQUEST back to Paypal:

```
private string GetPayPalResponse(Dictionary<string, string> formVals)
    {
        string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PaypalUrl"];

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        // Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(strRequest);

        foreach (string key in formVals.Keys)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", key, formVals[key]);
        }
        strRequest += sb.ToString();
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        string response = "";
        using (StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            streamOut.Write(strRequest);
            streamOut.Close();
            using (StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IPN script must have some sort of an error in it keeping it from returning a 200 OK response back to PayPal.  You'll need to run some tests to in order to find the problem, or you can probably just check your web logs to see the issue.

Here's an article about [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) you may be interested in. Following those steps you should be able to pin-point the problem.

Comment: So then when I do the post back of the REQUEST to Paypal, even though I get the VERIFIED response, the actual HTTP response must not be 200 correct?

Comment: You always POST back to PayPal to verify the IPN data, but then your script should complete successfully after that.  You must have some sort of an error in your code causing the IPN script to fail at some point.

Comment: I will check, but I am logging all errors & see none logged. My IPN listener first gets the response back from Paypal that was sent. If it was "VERIFIED" then I proceed to get the Request vals, the amount, the tracking id, etc. Then I complete the order and then send the exact same request back to Paypal. Is that not the right order?

I looked at my IPN history and the HTTP Response Code is 405. This code should be 200 correct?

Comment: Right, anything other than a 200 will cause their system to keep sending the IPN.  It sounds like you've got an additional call back to their server you don't need.  You receive the POST, then POST that back to PayPal before you do anything else to get verified or invalid.  If verified, then go ahead and save your vals and do whatever you need to do with the data.  No additional call back to PayPal is required at that point.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think that's what I'm doing wrong. I first get the initial response from Paypal via my IPN, then I get those REQUEST vals, process them AND then I send the response back to Paypal. When it seems I should get the request and then send it right back...then I process the vars.

I followed this tut and he only recieved the POST and processed the val ...

http://blog.liamcavanagh.com/2012/06/how-to-use-paypal-with-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Got it figured out, Paypals IP address was being blocked. So even though Paypal could contact my listener and I could process the REQUEST, the http status code of the listener was still 405. Got the IP unblocked and now it's 200. Thanks for the help!